# font-weight and font-size not working together

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Whenever I want to change the font-size of my text, the font-weight seems to revert back to it's default value in what I see on the browser.

When I inspect it, both font-size and font-weight seem to be applied and working fine. Not sure what the issue is. When I disable the font type I have linked below, it seems to be working fine.

The thing is, I have been using the same font below, and this issue just started occurring overnight. No clue what could have changed. Thank you.

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Oxygen',
    'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue',
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

#element {
font-weight: 700 !important;
font-size: 20px !important;
}

<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; width: 40vw; margin-left: 20px;"><div style="font-size: 24px; font-weight: 600;">Sell your clutter</div><div style="font-size: 20px; font-weight: 600;">Athens Locations</div><div style="width: 100%; height: 25vh;">House1</div><div>House2</div></div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to share HTML code as well?

Comment: @HardiShah Just shared, although not much help there.

Comment: As per the HTML you shared, there is not any ID named "element". And you are giving css to "element" Id. can you please cross verify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you changed or updated the browser that you usually uses ? Take a look at https://github.com/tailwindcss/tailwindcss/issues/1402

Comment: Oh interesting, maybe an auto updated browser bug then. Thank you!

Comment: Yep, this is a browser bug. Never seen a bug like this from Chrome, interesting!

Answer (score 1):

Similar thing happened with me. I tried multiple things, then I used Firefox instead of Chrome and it was working fine. Then only I came to know about bug.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that you're ID's and Classes matched the ones you set up in your HTML page. Either that or your browser might have the issue try updating it to the latest version if you haven't already. Because these days most of the CSS only works on modern browsers.